# How To Get Name of Calling Method and Executing Method of Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, func

I have some historical code and we want to get some data about how some methods are used. I am trying to access the name of the calling method as well as the name of the executing method using reflection. But I can only ever seem to get the name of the outer calling method.

We have a source method that does something like this:

```
public class DataBinder
{
    public IEnumerable<object> FindData(string id)
    {
        var data = Helper.MeasureExecution(() => DataHelper.GetData(id), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());

        return data;
    }
}
```

And a method in the static `Helper` class that does something like the following:

```
public static T MeasureExecution<T>(Func<T> func, MethodBase sourceMethod)
{
    T funcResult;

    funcResult = func();

    try
    {
        var executingMethod = string.Empty;

        if (func.Method!= null)
        {
            executingMethod = func.Method.Name;
        }

        LogDetails($"Method Being Executed: {executingMethod}, Executing Source Class: {sourceMethod.ReflectedType.Name}, Executing Source Method: {sourceMethod.Name});
    }
    catch { }

    return funcResult;
}
```

I would like to get the following `"Method Being Executed: GetData, Executing Source Class: DataBinder, Executing Source Method: FindData"`, but I always get `"Method Being Executed: FindData, Executing Source Class: DataBinder, Executing Source Method: FindData"`.

Does it have something to do with the lambda expression being static, or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression given in the lambda being a delegate, you will have to traverse into its content to get the actual method details. I suggest updating the parameter type for the Helper method (`MeasureExecution`) to be `Expression<Func<T>>` instead of `Func<T>` as an `Expression` type would allow you to easily examine the contents of a `Func`. I did try a sample with the below snippet and it worked as per the expectation. I used a static variable in place of your `LogDetails` to make my life easier in double checking what is being sent.

```
public static T MeasureExecution<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func, MethodBase sourceMethod)
        {
            T funcResult;

            funcResult = func.Compile()();

            try
            {
                var executingMethod = string.Empty;
                var methodExpression = func.Body as MethodCallExpression;

                if (methodExpression != null)
                {
                    executingMethod = methodExpression.Method != null ? methodExpression.Method.Name : "Cannot find method details";
                }

                MethodInformation = string.Format("Method Being Executed:  {0}, Executing Source Class: {1}, Executing Source Method: {2}", executingMethod, sourceMethod.ReflectedType.Name, sourceMethod.Name);
                }
                catch { }

                return funcResult;
        }

        public static string MethodInformation { get; private set; }
```

And this is the output I get -
*Method Being Executed:  GetData, Executing Source Class: DataBinder, Executing Source Method: FindData*

Comment: Keep in mind that this is going to re-compile the expression each and every time the method is invoked, even if you call it with the same lambda. It's also going to construct new Expression objects. You are going to pay a penalty, which may not be worth it (especially in a method called MeasureExecution) unless you figure a way to cache that compilation